# How to create Identity Server DB for SQLite?

Tags: c#, sqlite, identityserver4, data-migration

I have run `dotnet new is4ef` to create an Identity Server template.

Next I changed `UseSqlServer()` -> `UseSqlite()` in `Startup.cs`.

The program compiles, but the tables in the DB are not created when it runs.

How to create the suitable tables for the configuration store and operational store?

Comment: Run the migrations

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius How to run the migrations? How to obtain the migrations? I saw migrations for SQL Server. I need SQLite

Comment: [here](https://damienbod.com/2017/12/30/using-an-ef-core-database-for-the-identityserver4-configuration-data/) is the complete example with SQLite

Answer (score 1):

To create the DB, you need to run the migration:

```bash
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
dotnet ef migrations add 'initial' --project src/IdentityServer/IdentityServer.csproj --context PersistedGrantDbContext
```

Then you update the database by

```bash
dotnet ef database update --project src/IdentityServer/IdentityServer.csproj --context ConfigurationDbContext
```

And then the DBs are created.